# Linux Mint reboot freeze

Tags: reboot, freeze

I have almost succeeded with a USB dual boot installation of Linux Mint 19.2 on a Win 10 laptop. 
I am a Linux virgin, so have followed the instructions in a "monkey-see, monkey-do" method. This served me well right through to the end of the installation in a live session. After receiving a completion message, I was invited to reboot, at which point the system froze. 
Any pointers welcome, but please assume (correctly) that I have no functioning knowledge of Linux. Baby step by baby step please.

Comment: Ook; we were all primates once. A common issue is a corrupted ISO file. Did you use a checksum to verify the ISO you downloaded, following https://linuxmint.com/verify.php ? Did you download a 32-bit or 64-bit version? Did you download the edition with Cinnamon, xfce, or MATE? Please click [edit] to reply; please do not click Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Some graphics cards don't work well with the open-source driver present in Linux Mint, but there's a work-around. Before you start, though, please go to Windows, open a Command Prompt Window, and run `wmic computersystem get manufacturer,model,systemtype` then collect that information, and add it to your original question so we can see what kind of PC you have.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the PC, select booting from the version of Mint you installed, and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to force the boot menu of [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) to appear. Then, replace **quiet** where it appears in the commands for the first item in the GRUB menu with **nomodeset**, and then continue with booting. Here are two videos; the [first](https://www.linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/rosa/nomodeset_efi.webm) is for the EFI/UEFI boot configuration most common with Windows 10, and the [second](https://www.linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/rosa/nomodeset_bios.webm) is for the MBR boot process from Windows 7.

Once you get past that problem, you can install the drivers for your PC's video adapter.